# Android shape drawable xml not drawn on device nor emulator

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-widget

I just can't figure it out. I have this shape in res/drawable/start_light.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="20dp"
    android:thickness="0dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
</shape>
```

In res/values/styles.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="StartLight">
        <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/start_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And in main layout I have:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_height="150dp">
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/start_light" android:id="@+id/light5" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp"></ImageView>
    <View style="@style/StartLight" android:id="@+id/light4"></View>
    <View style="@style/StartLight" android:id="@+id/light3"></View>
    <View style="@style/StartLight" android:id="@+id/light2"></View>
    <View style="@style/StartLight" android:id="@+id/light1"></View>
</LinearLayout>
```

In ether way, using View or ImageView I dont see any red circles in my layout on emulator nor device. On xml graphical designer they are there. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace your shape drawable with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:thickness="20dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
 </shape>
```

Setting the thickness as 0 made it not visible on the emulator.
Here i set the innerRadius as 0.